# Client's variables from a list of arguments

Tags: python-2.7, client, variadic-functions

I tried tu run a TCP Client by using list of arguments. I don't want to type each time variables "host" and "port" so I wanted my program to take it from the list. But when I start it I've got error "name 'host' is not defined
name" and "name 'port' is not defined" (it stars working only when I declare "host" and "port" by myself). I put it all in main so why it doesn't see a declaraction of these two variables?

```
import socket
import sys
import getopt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = sys.argv[1:]
    argumentList = getopt.getopt(arguments, 'h:p:')[0]

    for arg, val in argumentList:
        if arg == '-h':
            host = val
        if arg == '-p':
            port = int(val)
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    client.connect((host, port))
    client.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\n\r\n'.format(host))
    print client.recv(1024)
```

Comment: how do you call your program? you should set `host` and `port` to default values (like -1) and check for it in case the caller forgets to pass the mandatory options.

Comment: Thanks for a clue it helped. :) Sorry for so late response, I'm afraid I just enteriely forgot to answer you.